# How to check if a django form is saved in db

Tags: django, django-models

I made a simple `ModelForm` in `Django` `1.7`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Biodata(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    room_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class BiodataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Biodata
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def getdata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BiodataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = request.POST
            firstname = post['first_name']
            lastname = post['last_name']
            newbiodata = form.save()
            return render(request, 'bio/index.html', {'first_name': firstname, 'last_name': lastname})
    else:
        form = BiodataForm()
    return render(request, 'bio/biodataform.html', {'form': form})
```

all things are working fine

**Question :**

How can I see my database and info saved in it using these forms ?

Comment: Your question is unclear...! do you want to check form saved information in code itself ? or in your actual database ?

Comment: i want to check if form is saved in actual database so that i can query for information given by someone through the form

Comment: what ...? for that you can use Daniel Roseman answer ...! what else you need ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.

1. **Trust Django**. Save the form and then pass the object you get into the template. If the object exists it should get passed into the template. Like so:

   ```
   def getdata(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = BiodataForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               post = request.POST
               newbiodata = form.save()
               return render(request, 'bio/index.html',
                   { 'first_name': newbiodata.firstname,
                     'last_name': newbiodata.lastname    })
   ```
2. **Ask for the object explicitly from the database**. Use thePrimary key (`pk`) of the object from the form to explicitly call it back from the database. This is probably overkill and will force an extra (probably redundant) query. The advantage is that if it doesn't save this will throw a very visible `ObjectDoesNotExist` Exception But if you are the paranoid sort, this will work:

   ```
   def getdata(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = BiodataForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               post = request.POST
               bio = form.save()
               newbiodata = models.Biodata.objects.get(pk=bio.pk) # get it back
               return render(request, 'bio/index.html',
                   { 'first_name': newbiodata.firstname,
                     'last_name': newbiodata.lastname    })
   ```

Comment: thanks man it worked but is it possible to do the same from any other file...and how can i make a primary key so that i can access and query for purticular's info...??

Answer (score 0):

You should not render a template on a successful post. Instead, you should redirect to a new URL. This gives you the perfect opportunity to fetch the new object from the database. In the form view:

```
newbiodata = form.save()
return redirect('show_biodata', kwargs={'pk': newbiodata.pk})
```

and now you can fetch it again in the show_biodata view:

```
def show_biodata(request, pk):
    biodata = BioData.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'bio/index.html', {'first_name': biodata.firstname, 'last_name': biodata.lastname})
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question i tried it but it is giving NoReverseMatch error - Reverse for 'show_biodata' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'pk': 8L}}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []...plz help me again

Comment: Well you need to actually create the URL entry for that view.

Comment: i m sorry but i did not understand what do u mean.. i have no clue sorry..can u explain more plz